Distribution Upgrade 22.04 to 24.04 freezes at "Cleaning Up"
I started the distribution upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 after it was reenabled in the last days. It has done well until the "Cleaning Up" step. It now hangs while "Searching for obsolete software" what can I do?

The distribution upgrade just needed a whole day to gather all obsolete software. It then continued.

do you know how many hours it took? I am stuck at the same step.

In my case it took about 30mins to get through this step, by far the longest part of the upgrade process.  Would be nice if there was some progess shown here since it did feel a bit broken.  But yes just leave it be and allow it to complete.
